# Difference in converting decimal values ​between local machine and docker container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core

I created the Webapp API, configured Docker-compose to upload the 3 containers with the database, api and web app. I am now facing a problem with converting decimal values.

In my development environment, when typing a value with decimal places everything goes normal (23,14). See the example in the images:
[image]
[image]
When I upload the containers, this behavior is different and when I put the same value in the container application, it treats the value differently. See the example in the image below.
[image]
[image]

Both the api and the webapp were configured to take the pt-BR localization pattern, however, in the container this configuration seems to be ignored.

WEBAPP

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      else
      {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
      }
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });

      var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
      var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
      {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture),
        SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture },
        SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture }
      };
      app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

    }
```

API

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

      // Definindo a cultura padrão: pt-BR
      var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") };
      app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
      {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "pt-BR", uiCulture: "pt-BR"),
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
      });

      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "APIProduto v1"));
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time of research and some unsuccessful attempts, I followed a colleague's suggestion to define the location of the containers, as a way to solve the problem, since the definition of culture in the asp.net core api and webapp were not enough to solve the problem.
I made locale settings in the Dockerfile and Docker-compose files and from there everything works as desired.

Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8
```

Docker-compose

```
environment:
     - LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8  
     - LANGUAGE=pt_BR  
     - LC_ALL=pt_BR.UTF-8
```